# Transfering GPX files from Basecamp to CSV files for use in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, gpx

How do I transfer GPX files from Garmin Basecamp to CSV files for use in ArcMap?

I have saved all my points and tracks in Basecamp and now need to plot them on ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

To export GPX files as CSV from Garmin Basecamp, select the waypoints you want to export and then:

1. Click File
2. Export
3. Export Selection
4. Save as Type csv and select where to save the file

You can find more information on Garmin's info page [here](https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=H1JPzheM626UvLBF60rpc9).

Alternatively, ArcMap can directly import gpx files using the GPX to Feature tool. Documentation on the tool is [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/gpx-to-features.htm).